# Formatting only the DOI using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, doi

I'm using biblatex and would like my DOIs to be printed (achieved thanks to `doi=true`) in a **different color and font** in the bibliography section.

Basically, they are formatted the same way as URL, which are quite large in my style. I would like both to reduce the font of DOIs, and display them in a lighter color.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,doi=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}


\begin{document}

Hello \cite{Smith12}

\printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{document}
```

With the following `mybib.bib`:

```
@article{Smith12,
    author    = {John Smith},
    title     = {A great article},
    journal   = {Journal of something},
    volume    = {1},
    number    = {1-3},
    pages     = {42--50},
    year      = {2012},
    doi       = {12.345/123456789},
}
```

**Note 1**: package `libertine` is not necessary, just it makes the URL font even larger.

**Note 2**: I do not want to change the URL font (which is easy), but just the DOI color and font.

Comment: Please show us a code example of what you have so far ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)). The solution will depend on the current style. What about the font of the URLs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could adjust the `doi+eprint+url` macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Smith12,
    author    = {John Smith},
    title     = {A great article},
    journal   = {Journal of something},
    volume    = {1},
    number    = {1-3},
    pages     = {42--50},
    year      = {2012},
    doi       = {12.345/123456789},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber,doi=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\color{red}\tiny\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}


\begin{document}

Hello \cite{Smith12}

\printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to the great [comment by @moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446145/formatting-only-the-doi-using-biblatex/446175?noredirect=1#comment1120567_446175) it is easier to just change the field format of the doi:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Smith12,
    author    = {John Smith},
    title     = {A great article},
    journal   = {Journal of something},
    volume    = {1},
    number    = {1-3},
    pages     = {42--50},
    year      = {2012},
    doi       = {12.345/123456789},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber,doi=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    \color{red}\tiny%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Hello \cite{Smith12}

\printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess normally you would redefine the field format for the DOI. The default is `\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}`. Depending on how other URL-like things should be handled it might be an option to redefine `\nolinkurl` instead.

Comment: @moewe Once more: Thanks a lot for your helpful comment!